# Declaring a CSS Module Class as a Variable in NextJS

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, jsx, css-modules

Please excuse me if I forget anything - this is my first post on Stack Overflow.

The function's purpose is to open and close my hamburger menu.
I have attached a snapshot of the JSX file where this issue is: [NavbarLinks.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RdIQ.png).
The lines of code that I am struggling with are 15 and 18 where I am trying to declare a CSS module class as a variable.

```
const [navLinkOpen, navLinkToggle] = useState(false);
  const handleNavLinksToggle = () => {
    navLinkToggle(!navLinkOpen);
  };

  const renderClasses = () => {
    let classes = {`${styles.navLinks}`};

    if (navLinkOpen) {
      classes += {`${styles.active}`};
    }

    return classes;
  };
```

I then call the returned class inside the ul tag on line 27.

```
<ul className={renderClasses}>
```

I have tried several variations of declaring this class as a variable, what I am showing you here is just my last attempt. I am aware that the attempt I am using has broken the code. - I am fairly new to JavaScript and instead of simply following YouTube guides, I learn better by trying things myself.

Please try and answer the question I have instead of suggesting an alternative method, purely because I just want to learn more about this! - but if you do have alternative methods of what I am trying to achieve here, I would very much like to see them too.

I'll also include a snapshot of the CSS Module file that I am working with just incase you may find it useful: [NavbarLinksStyle.module.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA4Fz.png)

Thanks in advance for any help - will be around to answer any questions.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, congrats on the post. It's very well explained. The code you shared seems to be pretty fine overall, but from what I can see you are missing the execution of the `renderClasses` function.

```js
const [navLinkOpen, navLinkToggle] = useState(false);
  const handleNavLinksToggle = () => {
    navLinkToggle(!navLinkOpen);
  };

  const renderClasses = () => {
    let classes = styles.navLinks;

    if (navLinkOpen) {
      classes += styles.active;
    }

    return classes;
  };

  {...}
    <ul className={renderClasses()}> 
  {...}
```

Also, you can achieve the same result by using a variable instead of a function:

```js
const renderClasses = `${styles.navLinks} ${navLinkOpen ? styles.active : ''}`;
```

**EDIT**: Also as @Mina pointed out you should get rid of the curly braces on your render function.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I have just taken a break to spend some time with my partner who has has to put up with me stressing over this on a weekend  but I’ll let you know how it goes in 30 mins. Thanks for the amazing response!

Comment: It worked! So simple! - I guess this is all just part of the learning process. I was reluctant to make a Stack Overflow account, I didn't think anybody would bother answering, I think you've just created a monster by showing me how useful this website is! Thank you again

Comment: Okay, how about this one... (I think my brain has turned to mush because it seems like it should be so simple).
How do I now change the hamburgerToggle class to color:white when the ul tag is active?
The hamburger icon is outside of the ul tag. I'm going to spend hours on this again, aren't I?

Comment: Since we know `ul` will be active when `navLinkOpen` is `true`, you can just toggle the class depending on the  state:
`<div className={navLinkOpen ? styles.buttonToggleActive : styles.buttonToggle} />`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't declare the classes variable with curly brackets.

```
  const renderClasses = () => {
    let classes = styles.navLinks

    if (navLinkOpen) {
      classes += styles.active
    }

  return classes;
};
```